# maximum mark of each subject in mysql

Tags: mysql, max

I need to a get the maximum mark of each subject,that student name in a table. There are six subjects. Please help me to generate MySQL query.

```
SELECT MAX(evs) FROM eee2sem AND name where name = MAX(evs);
```

This can be used to fetch only one subject result. Not overall maximum mark and the students Name, I need 6 results. Actually I need the maximum mark and the student name form every subject..

Comment: Read about `group by`

Comment: Share your table structure and describe the precise results you are looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT MAX(col1), MAX(col2), MAX(col3), MAX(col4), MAX(col5), MAX(col6) FROM YourTable;
```

Comment: Does this work? can you post sqlfiddle with example?

Comment: If this is the answer then something's very wrong with the design!